# Where can I find that AlertDialog.Builder.setItems has a return type -> dialog, which?

Tags: android, android-view

I visit a Tutorial and there was this code:

```
pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems) {dialog, which ->
    when(which) {
              0 -> Toast.makeText(this@Test, "Gallerie auswahl kommt noch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              1 -> Toast.makeText(this@Test, "Kamera Auswahl kommt noch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

But from where did I get the *dialog* and the *which* return value?  I cannot find that in the Documentation.
[Documentation Dialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setItems(kotlin.Array,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

The thing is, I want to understand where can I find this method in the documentation that I can use functions, methods, code....without YouTube or any other help. (Only Help from the documentation)

**Complete Code**

```
class Test : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener{
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
   
            binding.tvAddImage.setOnClickListener(this)
          }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            R.id.tv_add_image -> {
                val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                pictureDialog.setTitle("Aktion auswählen")
                val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Fotos aus der Gallerie auswählen", "Foto aufnehmen")
                pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems) {dialog, which ->
                    when(which) {
                        0 -> Toast.makeText(this@Test, "Gallerie auswahl kommt noch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        1 -> Toast.makeText(this@Test, "Kamera Auswahl kommt noch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```